# How to position python widget labels from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470038/python-str-object-has-no-attribute-config), I created a grid-like table.
I have tried to position labels in a column according to a list ['5','4','3','2','1']. What I get is the layout of the label starts from 1 at the top down to 5. How can I reversed the order to start with 5 at the top to 1 at the bottom?.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

# Create variables for these for the grid width/height
width = 5
height = ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']


def fill_auto():
    for i in range(1, 6):
        rd_row = random.randrange(0, 5)
        rd_col = random.randrange(0, width)
        rd_num = random.randrange(50, 100)
        print(rd_row, rd_col, rd_num)
        # Set the label text
        matrix[rd_row][rd_col].config(text=str(rd_num))


root = Tk()
root.geometry('+0+0')
root.configure(bg='black')
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()


# Helper function to create a label
def make_label(x, y):
    label_box = 'box' + str(y)
    l = Label(frame1, width=5, relief='solid', text=label_box)
    l.grid(column=x, row=y)
    return l


# Using list comprehension to create 2d list
matrix = [[make_label(x, y) for x in range(width)] for y in height]


frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack()
btn = Button(frame2, text='start', command=fill_auto)
btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `make_label` function you use `y` for both the label text *and* the row number, so when the label is `5` it's going to be on the fifth row.

In contradiction, in your `matrix` variable the first row actually does contain the labels with the highest number. You can see this by changing one of the labels:

```
matrix[1][1].config(text='test')
```

which, unintuitively, produces this:

[image]

---

To get the grid of the GUI in line with the `matrix` you can make a small change in creating the widgets:

```
# Helper function to create a label
def make_label(x, y, t):
    label_box = 'box' + str(t)
    l = Label(frame1, width=5, relief='solid', text=label_box)
    l.grid(column=x, row=y)
    return l

# Using list comprehension to create 2d list
matrix = [[make_label(x, y, t) for x in range(width)] for (y, t) in enumerate(height)]
```

Which produces this:

[image]